# How to join dynamically named columns into dictionary?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given these data frames:

```
IncomingCount
-------------------------
Venue|Date    | 08 | 10 |
-------------------------
Hotel|20190101| 15 | 03 |
Beach|20190101| 93 | 45 |

OutgoingCount
-------------------------
Venue|Date    | 07 | 10 | 
-------------------------
Beach|20190101| 30 | 5  |
Hotel|20190103| 05 | 15 |
```

How can I possibly merge (full join) the two tables resulting in something as following without having to manually loop through each row of both tables?

```
Dictionary:
[
 {"Venue":"Hotel", "Date":"20190101", "08":{ "IncomingCount":15 }, "10":{ "IncomingCount":03 } },
 {"Venue":"Beach", "Date":"20190101", "07":{ "OutgoingCount":30 }, "08":{ "IncomingCount":93 }, "10":{ "IncomingCount":45, "OutgoingCount":15 } },
 {"Venue":"Hotel", "Date":"20190103", "07":{ "OutgoingCount":05 }, "10":{ "OutgoingCount":15 } }
]
```

The conditions are:

1. Venue and Date columns act like join conditions.
2. The other columns, represented in numbers, are dynamically created.
3. If dynamically column does not exist, it gets excluded( or included with None as value ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's pretty fiddly, but it can be done by making use of the `create_map` function from spark.

basically divide the columns into four groups: keys (venue, date), common (10), only incoming (08), only outgoing (07).

then create mappers per group (except keys), mapping only what's available per group. apply mapping, drop the old column and rename the mapped column to the old name.

lastly convert all rows to dict (from df's rdd) and collect.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map, col, lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('hotels_and_beaches').getOrCreate()

incoming_counts = spark.createDataFrame([('Hotel', 20190101, 15, 3), ('Beach', 20190101, 93, 45)], ['Venue', 'Date', '08', '10']).alias('inc')
outgoing_counts = spark.createDataFrame([('Beach', 20190101, 30, 5), ('Hotel', 20190103, 5, 15)], ['Venue', 'Date', '07', '10']).alias('out')

df = incoming_counts.join(outgoing_counts, on=['Venue', 'Date'], how='full')

outgoing_cols = {c for c in outgoing_counts.columns if c not in {'Venue', 'Date'}}
incoming_cols = {c for c in incoming_counts.columns if c not in {'Venue', 'Date'}}

common_cols = outgoing_cols.intersection(incoming_cols)

outgoing_cols = outgoing_cols.difference(common_cols)
incoming_cols = incoming_cols.difference(common_cols)

for c in common_cols:
    df = df.withColumn(
        c + '_new', create_map(
            lit('IncomingCount'), col('inc.{}'.format(c)),
            lit('OutgoingCount'), col('out.{}'.format(c)),
        )
    ).drop(c).withColumnRenamed(c + '_new', c)

for c in incoming_cols:
    df = df.withColumn(
        c + '_new', create_map(
            lit('IncomingCount'), col('inc.{}'.format(c)),
        )
    ).drop(c).withColumnRenamed(c + '_new', c)

for c in outgoing_cols:
    df = df.withColumn(
        c + '_new', create_map(
            lit('OutgoingCount'), col('out.{}'.format(c)),
        )
    ).drop(c).withColumnRenamed(c + '_new', c)

result = df.coalesce(1).rdd.map(lambda r: r.asDict()).collect()
print(result)
```

result:

```
[{'Venue': 'Hotel', 'Date': 20190101, '10': {'OutgoingCount': None, 'IncomingCount': 3}, '08': {'IncomingCount': 15}, '07': {'OutgoingCount': None}}, {'Venue': 'Hotel', 'Date': 20190103, '10': {'OutgoingCount': 15, 'IncomingCount': None}, '08': {'IncomingCount': None}, '07': {'OutgoingCount': 5}}, {'Venue': 'Beach', 'Date': 20190101, '10': {'OutgoingCount': 5, 'IncomingCount': 45}, '08': {'IncomingCount': 93}, '07': {'OutgoingCount': 30}}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure you'll get the nesting you want if you don't create the map columns

Comment: You're right, my previous comment wasn't true and I deleted it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I can get this so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dd1 = {'venue': ['hotel', 'beach'], 'date':['20190101', '20190101'], '08': [15, 93], '10':[3, 45]}
dd2 = {'venue': ['beach', 'hotel'], 'date':['20190101', '20190103'], '07': [30, 5], '10':[5, 15]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dd1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dd2)

df1.columns = [f"IncomingCount:{x}" if x not in ['venue', 'date'] else x for x in df1.columns]
df2.columns = [f"OutgoingCount:{x}" if x not in ['venue', 'date'] else x for x in df2.columns ]

ll_dd = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['venue', 'date'], how='outer').to_dict('records')
ll_dd = [{k:v for k,v in dd.items() if not pd.isnull(v)} for dd in ll_dd]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'venue': 'hotel',
  'date': '20190101',
  'IncomingCount:08': 15.0,
  'IncomingCount:10': 3.0},
 {'venue': 'beach',
  'date': '20190101',
  'IncomingCount:08': 93.0,
  'IncomingCount:10': 45.0,
  'OutgoingCount:07': 30.0,
  'OutgoingCount:10': 5.0},
 {'venue': 'hotel',
  'date': '20190103',
  'OutgoingCount:07': 5.0,
  'OutgoingCount:10': 15.0}]
```

Comment: Thanks, but due to system constraint I am having I can't use pandas. I am looking for pyspark solution.

Answer (score 0):

The final result as desired by the OP is a `list` of `dictionaries`, where all rows from the DataFrame which have same `Venue` and `Date` have been clubbed together.

```
# Creating the DataFrames
df_Incoming = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Hotel','20190101',15,3),('Beach','20190101',93,45)],('Venue','Date','08','10'))
df_Incoming.show()
+-----+--------+---+---+
|Venue|    Date| 08| 10|
+-----+--------+---+---+
|Hotel|20190101| 15|  3|
|Beach|20190101| 93| 45|
+-----+--------+---+---+
df_Outgoing = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Beach','20190101',30,5),('Hotel','20190103',5,15)],('Venue','Date','07','10'))
df_Outgoing.show()
+-----+--------+---+---+
|Venue|    Date| 07| 10|
+-----+--------+---+---+
|Beach|20190101| 30|  5|
|Hotel|20190103|  5| 15|
+-----+--------+---+---+
```

The idea is to create a `dictionary` from each `row` and have the all `rows` of the `DataFrame` stored as dictionaries in one big `list`. And as a final step, we club those dictionaries together which have same `Venue` and `Date`.

Since, all `rows` in the DataFrame are stored as `Row()` objects, we use [collect()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=collect#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect) function to return all records as `list` of `Row()`. Just to illustrate the output -

```
print(df_Incoming.collect())
[Row(Venue='Hotel', Date='20190101', 08=15, 10=3), Row(Venue='Beach', Date='20190101', 08=93, 10=45)]
```

But, since we want `list` of `dictionaries`, we can use `list comprehensions` to convert them to a one  -

```
list_Incoming = [row.asDict() for row in df_Incoming.collect()]
print(list_Incoming)
[{'10': 3, 'Date': '20190101', 'Venue': 'Hotel', '08': 15}, {'10': 45, 'Date': '20190101', 'Venue': 'Beach', '08': 93}]
```

But, since the numeric columns have been in the form like `"08":{ "IncomingCount":15 }`, instead of `"08":15`, so we employ `dictionary comprehensions` to convert them into this form -

```
list_Incoming = [ {k:v if k in ['Venue','Date'] else {'IncomingCount':v} for k,v in dict_element.items()} for dict_element in list_Incoming]
print(list_Incoming)
[{'10': {'IncomingCount': 3}, 'Date': '20190101', 'Venue': 'Hotel', '08': {'IncomingCount': 15}}, {'10': {'IncomingCount': 45}, 'Date': '20190101', 'Venue': 'Beach', '08': {'IncomingCount': 93}}]
```

Similarly, we do for `OutgoingCount`

```
list_Outgoing = [row.asDict() for row in df_Outgoing.collect()]
list_Outgoing = [ {k:v if k in ['Venue','Date'] else {'OutgoingCount':v} for k,v in dict_element.items()} for dict_element in list_Outgoing]
print(list_Outgoing)
[{'10': {'OutgoingCount': 5}, 'Date': '20190101', 'Venue': 'Beach', '07': {'OutgoingCount': 30}}, {'10': {'OutgoingCount': 15}, 'Date': '20190103', 'Venue': 'Hotel', '07': {'OutgoingCount': 5}}]
```

**Final Step:** Now, that we have created the requisite `list` of `dictionaries`, we need to club the list together on the basis of `Venue` and `Date`.

```
from copy import deepcopy
def merge_lists(list_Incoming, list_Outgoing):
    # create dictionary from list_Incoming:
    dict1 = {(record['Venue'], record['Date']): record  for record in list_Incoming}

    #compare elements in list_Outgoing to those on list_Incoming:

    result = {}
    for record in list_Outgoing:
        ckey = record['Venue'], record['Date']
        new_record = deepcopy(record)
        if ckey in dict1:
            for key, value in dict1[ckey].items():
                if key in ('Venue', 'Date'):
                    # Do not merge these keys
                    continue
                # Dict's "setdefault" finds a key/value, and if it is missing
                # creates a new one with the second parameter as value
                new_record.setdefault(key, {}).update(value)

        result[ckey] = new_record

    # Add values from list_Incoming that were not matched in list_Outgoing:
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        if key not in result:
            result[key] = deepcopy(value)

    return list(result.values())

res = merge_lists(list_Incoming, list_Outgoing)
print(res)
[{'10': {'OutgoingCount': 5, 'IncomingCount': 45}, 
  'Date': '20190101', 
  'Venue': 'Beach', 
  '08': {'IncomingCount': 93}, 
  '07': {'OutgoingCount': 30}
 },

 {'10': {'OutgoingCount': 15}, 
   'Date': '20190103', 
   'Venue': 'Hotel', 
   '07': {'OutgoingCount': 5}
 }, 

 {'10': {'IncomingCount': 3}, 
  'Date': '20190101', 
  'Venue': 'Hotel', 
  '08': {'IncomingCount': 15}
 }]
```